# Embed current date into URL (matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, url

I want to download a file from the following link:
https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25_1hr.pl?file=gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.f039&lev_surface=on&var_CAPE=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.2019060206

How can I embded the current date, run time and forecast hour in the URL after predefining them? I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
myrun = 00; % 00 06 12 18
mydate = 20190603; % yearmonthday
myforecasthour = 039; % t + number of hours ahead
fullURL=['https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25_1hr.pl?file=gfs.t',num2str(myrun,'%02.f'),'z.pgrb2.0p25.f',num2str(myforecasthour,'%03.f'),'&lev_surface=on&var_CAPE=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.',num2str(mydate)'];

filename = 'cape_test';
urlwrite(fullURL,filename);
```

Comment: [websave](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/websave.html)

Comment: You have a stray single quote `'` at the end of the string right before the closing square bracket `]`. That is causing `mydate` to be transposed resulting in a 8x1 column vector instead of the expected row vector. For questions like this, please include the error message you receive rather than just saying "it doesn't work."